# how to addListener in a chartwrapper GoogleCharts

Tags: javascript, charts, graphing

I have a dashboard (dash) and a control wrapper (chart)

what I am trying to do is have a series toggled **on/off** by a click. I have been able to toggle a series before but never inside a dashboard or wrapper. is this feature supported with a wrapper? 
I cannot figure out the syntax to get this to work

here is my entire code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['controls', 'charteditor']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('date', 'Date'); 
        data.addColumn('number', 'series1');
        data.addColumn('number', 'series2');
        data.addRows([
          [new Date(2015, 11, 15, 1, 30), 10, 100],
          [new Date(2015, 11, 16, 2, 30), 20, 90],
          [new Date(2015, 11, 17, 3, 30), 30, 80],
          [new Date(2015, 11, 18, 4, 50), 40, 70],
          [new Date(2015, 11, 19, 13, 11), 50, 60],
          [new Date(2015, 11, 20, 23, 59), 60, 50],
        ]);

    var dash = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard'));

    var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        controlType: 'ChartRangeFilter',
        containerId: 'control_div',
        options: {
            filterColumnIndex: 0,
            ui: {
                chartOptions: {
                    height: 50,
                    width: 1280,
                    chartArea: {
                        width: '80%'
                    }
                },              
            },          
        }
    }); 

    var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        chartType: 'LineChart',
        containerId: 'chart_div'
    });



    function setOptions (wrapper) {
        wrapper.setOption('title', 'Avg Military Strength');
        wrapper.setOption('height', 400);
        wrapper.setOption('width', 1280);
        wrapper.setOption('chartArea.width', '80%');
        wrapper.setOption('animation.duration', 0);
    }

    function showHideSeries () {
    var sel = dash.getSelection();      

    // if selection length is 0, we deselected an element
    if (sel.length > 0) {

        // if row is undefined, we clicked on the legend
        if (sel[0].row == null) {           

            var col = sel[0].column;

            if (col > 0) {

                alert('hide the data?'); //i can get this alert
                // hide the data series 


                    columns[col] = {
                        label: data.getColumnLabel(col),
                        type: data.getColumnType(col),
                        calc: function () {
                            return null;
                        }                       

                    };

                    alert('grey the data?');//i cannot get this alert
                    // grey out the legend entry
                    series[col - 1].color = '#CCCCCC';
                }
                else {
                    // show the data series
                    columns[col] = col;
                    series[col - 1].color = null;
                }                   


            var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
            view.setColumns(columns);
            chart.draw(view, options);
        }
    }
}


    setOptions(chart);   

    dash.bind([control], [chart]);
    dash.draw(data);

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart , 'ready', function(){
         google.visualization.events.addListener(chart ,'select', showHideSeries);
    });


}
</script>

<div id="dashboard">
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
    <div id="control_div"></div>
</div>
```

and here is the part that is giving me particular trouble (specifically the first 2 lines)

```
function showHideSeries () {
    var sel = dash.getSelection();      

    // if selection length is 0, we deselected an element
    if (sel.length > 0) {

        // if row is undefined, we clicked on the legend
        if (sel[0].row == null) {           

            var col = sel[0].column;

            if (col > 0) {

                alert('hide the data?'); //i can get this alert
                // hide the data series 


                    columns[col] = {
                        label: data.getColumnLabel(col),
                        type: data.getColumnType(col),
                        calc: function () {
                            return null;
                        }                       

                    };

                    alert('grey the data?');//i cannot get this alert
                    // grey out the legend entry
                    series[col - 1].color = '#CCCCCC';
                }
                else {
                    // show the data series
                    columns[col] = col;
                    series[col - 1].color = null;
                }                   


            var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
            view.setColumns(columns);
            chart.draw(view, options);
        }
    }
}
```

The alert gets sent, so I believe I am calling it correctly, but it doesn't return anything for subsequent future clicks ceases to return the alert.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

edit: i have narrowed it down further to the part of the function where it nulls data points. i'm recycling this function from something that has worked before so i'm very confused why i can call the function, yet it is now failing once loaded.

```
          if (col > 0) {

                alert('hide the data?'); //i can get this alert
                // hide the data series                     

                columns[col] = {
                    label: data.getColumnLabel(col),
                    type: data.getColumnType(col),
                    calc: function () {
                        return null;
                    }                       

                };

                alert('grey the data?');//i cannot get this alert
                // grey out the legend entry
                series[col - 1].color = '#CCCCCC';
            }
            else {
                // show the data series
                columns[col] = col;
                series[col - 1].color = null;
            }
```

Comment: It's working to me, I get both alerts each time I select a point in the chart.

Comment: could you please check this again? i have further narrowed the problem. the problem isn't when you select a timepoint that it doesn't popup with the coordinates. rather the problem is when you click on a series name what is suppose to happen is the line disappears and the series key goes gray. with this it just stops working on the first click about halfway thru